# Создание экземпляров класса в задачах (потоках)

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как создать экземпляр класса в "потоке" Task так, чтобы он был доступен только из этого "потока" Task (чтобы не было состояния гонки)?

Comment: Ну если у класса нет статических свойств, то и гонки не будет, если вы создадите в таске экземпляр и никому его не будете показывать.

Comment: Переменная созданная в потоке и так будет доступна только в потоке. Если же вы создаете объект и передаете ссылку, например, в какой нибудь статический объект или объект, доступный другим потокам, то можно использовать атрибут [ThreadStatic] для того, чтобы объект по ссылке был доступен только потоку, который его создал

Comment: А можно увидеть воспроизводимый пример кода, который показывает эту "гонку"? Возможно вы пытаетесь исправить симптомы, а не источник проблемы. ([XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567))